# Mate desktop freezes the connection over RDP while unpainting GUI elements

Tags: server, vpn, remote-desktop, mate

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS on a remote VM(on vSphere) which needs to be connected through a VPN. I mostly access it through SSH. But I have installed Mate Desktop Environment(along with xrdp) to access some GUI components for some work.  I use Remote Desktop Connection(RDC) program on Windows 10 to login into GUI.

Whenever I minimize or close an application the graphical "unpainting" takes some time to finish. And that process will get stuck in between the process many times. I usually kill it forcefully through Task Manager tool. When I re-login I see the remote machine state as it is and no application is crashed during that process. So it only crashes RDC's connection but the OS does not hang.

Is there a way to tweak UI to use less resources over RDC application?

[image]

*Slow action of unpainting.*

Comment: I removed that wallpaper and set one of the default wallpaper. Looks like the unpainting action is faster now and does not freeze the connection.

Comment: You do release MATE & flavors of Ubuntu for 16.04 are EOL (except for Kylin which was given 5 year support by Canonical). Only Unity 7 (default desktop), server (no desktop) and Kylin are still supported on 16.04 LTS; security updates ceased months ago for other desktops including MATE.

Comment: @guiverc I am not aware of that but only Mate desktop works while accessing ubuntu server v16 through RDP. So setup MATE.

Comment: If you wanted proof - https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425  ; whilst your chosen desktop is EOL & thus doesn't receive patches or security fixes, your base system still does.  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to view your current status for your existing system.  FYI only.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the introduction to that command and the EOL notice webpage. You are right about it and also checked the command with `--show-unsupported` option where I saw `mate` components listed. 

I am not disagreeing with you. But currently I need solution for this problem. I cannot uninstall MATE without finding working alternative DE over RDP. I am basically asking for desktop tweaks which can make it lightweight and not hog on VM resources. Like the wallpaper change I mentioned on first comment some tweak should help out ease the usage of desktop.